# Property Access Expressions of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, expression

I'm reading JavaScript the definitive guide and there is code:

```
var o = {x:1,y:{z:3}}; // An example object
var a = [o,4,[5,6]]; // An example array that contains the object
o.x // => 1: property x of expression o
o.y.z // => 3: property z of expression o.y
o["x"] // => 1: property x of object o
a[1] // => 4: element at index 1 of expression a
a[2]["1"] // => 6: element at index 1 of expression a[2]
a[0].x // => 1: property x of expression a[0]
```

None of this except the last line is in question to me. How does a[0].x evaluate to 1? There is no property x belonging to the multidimensional array 'a'. I don't understand this. Is the property a[0].x being found in 'o'? This is confusing to me...

Thanks in advance for any comments or answers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line defines `o`, and the second sets `a[0]` as `o`, so we have...

```
a[0] === {x:1,y:{z:3}};
```

Therefore:

```
a[0].x === 1;
```

This also  means the following is true:

```
a[0].y.z === 3;
```

So you were correct in saying that the property `a[0].x` being found in `o`.

Comment: I'm going to have to give this one to the first reply. I must be seeing blurry because I believe I mistook that o for a 0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`a[0]` is equal to object `o` and you understand 3th row, where is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

'a' is an array, so 'a' can store multiple values and each of this value is stored in unique place. to get a value from array you have to know where it is stored (in what place). to get to your example, you have array called a:

var a = [o,4,[5,6]];

when adding values to array, by default they are stored in a positions starting from 0. so in array a on 0 position there is an object o (defined one line before this statement), on position 1 there is a value 4, and on position 2 there is another array [5, 6].

to get a value from array, you need to know its position, so to get an object o from array a, you just have to write:

a[0]

so this is the same as using an object o (because o is in the position 0 in this array).

objects have properties. to get property from object you must use . (dot) operator (there are other ways also). so to get property x from object o you need to write this:

o.x

and to conclude this, by writing a[0].x you are just saying give me o.x, it is the same thing.